# Melting repeated child nodes XML into a tidy data set using R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I am trying to build a data mash-up from a wide variety o security controls in R.  I have had great success with the devices that output CSV, JSON, etc,  but XML is really tripping me up.  You will quickly see that I am not the boss R developer I wish to be, but I greatly appreciate any help once could provide.  Here is a simplified version of the XML I am trying to parse.

```
 <devices>
    <host id="169274" persistent_id="21741">
      <ip>some_IP_here</ip>
      <hostname>Some_DNS_name_here </hostname>
      <netbiosname>Some_NetBios_Name_here</netbiosname>
      <hscore>663</hscore>
      <howner>4</howner>
      <assetvalue>4</assetvalue>
      <os>Unix Variant</os>
      <nbtshares/>
      <fndvuln id="534" port="80" proto="tcp"/>
      <fndvuln id="1191" port="22" proto="tcp"/>
    </host>
    <host id="169275" persistent_id="21003">
      <ip>some_IP_here</ip>
      <hostname>Some_DNS_name_here </hostname>
      <netbiosname>Some_NetBios_Name_here</netbiosname>
      <hscore>0</hscore>
      <howner>4</howner>
      <assetvalue>4</assetvalue>
      <os>OS Undetermined</os>
      <nbtshares/>
      <fndvuln id="5452" port="ip" proto="ip"/>
      <fndvuln id="5092" port="123" proto="udp"/>
      <fndvuln id="16157" port="123" proto="udp"/>
    </host>
</devices>
```

The end result that I am hoping to achieve is a tidy R dataframe that I can use for analysis.  It a perfect world it would like as follows

```
host           ip            hostname            netbiosname     VulnID   port   protocol
1 169274 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here  Some_NetBios_Name_here  534      80     tcp
2 169274 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here  Some_NetBios_Name_here  1191     22     tcp
3 169275 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here  Some_NetBios_Name_here  5452     ip     ip
4 169275 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here  Some_NetBios_Name_here  5092     123    udp
5 169275 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here  Some_NetBios_Name_here  16157    123    udp
```

On the simplest level, I have no problem parsing the XML and extracting the data I need to build the basic dataframe.  However, I struggle with how to iterate through the parsed XML and essentially create a separate line for each time the fndvuln element appears in parent XML node.

So far, I am guessing it is best to load each element individually and then bind them at the end.  I am thinking this would allow me to use sapply to run through the various instances of fndvuln and create a separate entry. so far, I have this for the basic structure:

```
library(XML)

setwd("My_file_location_here")

xmlfile <- "vuln.xml"
xmldoc <- xmlParse(xmlfile)
vuln <-getNodeSet(xmldoc, "//host")
x <- lapply(vuln, function(x)  data.frame(host = xpathSApply(x, "." , xmlGetAttr, "id"),
                                        ip = xpathSApply(x, ".//ip", xmlValue),
                                        hostname = xpathSApply(x, ".//hostname", xmlValue),
                                        netbiosname = xpathSApply(x, ".//netbiosname", xmlValue) ))

do.call("rbind", x)
```

Which basically gives me this:

```
    host           ip            hostname            netbiosname
1 169274 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here  Some_NetBios_Name_here
2 169275 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here  Some_NetBios_Name_here
```

Not sure how I would go about doing the rest.  Also, because this device will kick out quite a hefty XML file, knowing how to do this efficiently would be my end goal.

Comment: do you mind mentioning the weblink?

Comment: You will want to create a second data.frame with ip and port, then merge it on to the one you already made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host, ip, hostname, etc will be repeated when you add the fndvuln elements to your data.frame  (try `data.frame("a", 1:3)`)

```
x <- lapply(vuln, function(x)  data.frame(
    host = xpathSApply(x, "." , xmlGetAttr, "id"),
     ip  = xpathSApply(x, ".//ip", xmlValue),
hostname = xpathSApply(x, ".//hostname", xmlValue),
  VulnID = xpathSApply(x, ".//fndvuln" , xmlGetAttr, "id"),
   port  = xpathSApply(x, ".//fndvuln" , xmlGetAttr, "port") ))

do.call("rbind", x)
    host           ip            hostname VulnID port
1 169274 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here     534   80
2 169274 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here    1191   22
3 169275 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here    5452   ip
4 169275 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here    5092  123
5 169275 some_IP_here Some_DNS_name_here   16157  123
```

Comment: Hi Chris, this all makes a lot of sense now.  Thanks so much for the help.